# Click on TextView from RecyclerView does not work, click on Button does

Tags: java, android-activity, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, listadapter

Now that I got my RecyclerView working, and I can communicate between my Activity and my Adapter, I wanted to create an OnClickListener, which I did with success.

But somehow, it only works on buttons, not on other items.

In the Layout of my RecyclerView, I am having the following:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWebsite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="tvWebsite" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWebsite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
```

So the TextView is clickable. The button is too, but that is default behaviour.

In my Adapter class, I am having the following:

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Company> companyname;

    public CompanyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Company> list)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        companyname = list;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        TextView tvCompanyName;
        TextView tvVatID;
        TextView tvPostalCode;
        TextView tvPhoneNumber;
        TextView tvProprietorName;
        TextView tvWebsite;
        TextView tvEmail;
        TextView tvFirstAvailableDate;
        TextView tvFirstAvailableTimeBlock;
        TextView tvAvailableInPostalCode;
        TextView tvAvailableNumberOfPersons;
        Button btnWebsite;




        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            tvCompanyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);
            tvVatID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVatNo);
            tvPostalCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostalCode);
            tvPhoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
            tvProprietorName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProprietorName);
            tvWebsite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvWebsite);
            tvEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
            tvFirstAvailableDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFrstAvailableDate);
            tvFirstAvailableTimeBlock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstAvailableTimeBlock);
            tvAvailableInPostalCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostalCodeAvailable);
            tvAvailableNumberOfPersons = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAvailableNumberOfPersons);
            btnWebsite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnWebsite);
            tvWebsite.setClickable(true);


            tvWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mContext instanceof SearchForHelp) {
                        ((SearchForHelp) mContext).ClickWebsite();
                    }

                }
            });






            btnWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mContext instanceof SearchForHelp) {
                        ((SearchForHelp) mContext).ClickButton();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }





    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CompanyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CompanyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(companyname.get(i));

        viewHolder.tvCompanyName.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrCompanyName());
        viewHolder.tvVatID.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrVatID());
        viewHolder.tvPostalCode.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrPostalCode());
        viewHolder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrPhoneNumber());
        viewHolder.tvProprietorName.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrProprietorName());
        viewHolder.tvWebsite.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrWebsite());
        viewHolder.tvEmail.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrEmail());
        viewHolder.tvFirstAvailableDate.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrFirstAvailableDate());
        viewHolder.tvFirstAvailableTimeBlock.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrFirstAvailableTimeBlock());
        viewHolder.tvAvailableInPostalCode.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrAvailableInPostalCode());
        viewHolder.tvAvailableNumberOfPersons.setText(companyname.get(i).getStrAvailableNumberOfPersons());

        viewHolder.tvWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(getClass(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                //viewHolder.tvCompanyName.setText("Changed");


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return companyname.size();
    }
}
```

And finally, in my Activity:

```
public void ClickButton()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on Button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public void ClickWebsite()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on TextView",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Please note, that

```
tvWebsite.setClickable(true);
```

has been added to see if it made any difference, but it didn't.

If I click on the button, it toastes "Clicked on button", but if I click on the TextView, nothing happens.

So what do I miss in order to make the TextView tvWebsite clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `tvWebsite.setClickable(true);`

And you are setting click listener for `tvWebsite` in `onBindViewHolder` callback again.

You need to remove this code from `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
viewHolder.tvWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(getClass(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                //viewHolder.tvCompanyName.setText("Changed");


            }
        });
```

---------rest is fine.

Comment: Wow, was it THAT easy?! I just didn't see that OnClick. Thank you so very much!
BTW, I knew that the tvWebsite.setClickable wasn't needed, but I tried to use it in a desperate attempt to make it work!